# Paper submission related query

Tags: publications, peer-review, paper-submission

What does " securing reviewers" means when you submit a paper? Does that mean that the AE thinks that the paper is within the scope of the journal but he or she has not been able to find reviewers to take a look at the paper?

Comment: "phd" does not seem like an appropriate tag for this.  Perhaps peer-review or something more on topic.

Comment: "paper-submission" I would suggest as a tag.

Answer (score 1):

Every system is different and I haven't seen that status, but I certainly infer it means the AE is lining up reviewers.  That means the AE (and EIC) has not rejected it out of hand, but it doesn't guarantee that it will not eventually be rejected as out of scope.  That could happen if the reviewers note the issue, or if the AE has trouble finding reviewers and eventually gives up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, well it's been 7 days since I submitted the paper, in  an AIP journal. They are showing "securing reviewers" in the check status option.

Comment: It can take many weeks to line up reviewers.

Comment: Thank you sir, for your prompt reply. You had given me an advice a few days back on a paper pending revision. I was getting nervous and anxious. Two days back I got an acceptance .

Comment: Congratulations :)